# Security of MEVN application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose

I want to know how I can care about MEVN application's security. What things do I want to do to make my app use maximum security?

Comment: "How do I make my house secure?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering how to increase the security of any web application, **Authentication** and **Authorization** is the way to go.

- For the Server Side (node.js) it is extremely important that only **authorized users** can access your endpoints. You can achieve this using tools such as **jwt tokens**, which allows us to securely transmit JSON between parties (Server and Database) or (Server and Client Side).

You can read more about jwt and beare tokens here:
https://jwt.io/introduction

- For the Client-side (vue.js) it is vital that you add an additional attribute to the routes so that you can filter which users can access which routes. This is done by adding a meta attribute to our routes array so that only authenticated users are able to access specific routes.

```
   routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
            meta: {
                guest: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: Register,
            meta: {
                guest: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'userboard',
            component: UserBoard,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/admin',
            name: 'admin',
            component: Admin,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                is_admin : true
            }
        },
    ]
```

You can learn more about routes here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

All in all, Authentication and Authorization are vital for increasing web apps security, I recommend reading more about this topics if you're planning to deploy your application.